# Is there a cleaner way of executing this git workflow?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am running a team of 3 junior developers who are all working from on code the same Gitlab repository. I have adopted the following workflow for syncronising changes. It works but it's quite cumbersome and I feel like I am missing a cleaner way of doing this. The master branch is protected so only I can push or merge into it.

The workflow is as follows:

- Pull the master

  ```
  git pull origin master
  ```
- Create a local development branch

  ```
  git checkout -b master_teammember1dev
  ```
- Make changes, commit them to the master_teammember1dev branch and push them up to Gitlab

  ```
  git commit -am "changes"
  git push origin master_teammember1dev
  ```
- Create a merge request, which I will review and merge into the master

Once the merge request has been approved, re sync local repo with Gitlab remote:

- Pull the copy

  ```
  git pull origin master
  ```
- Delete the local dev branch

  ```
  git branch -D master_teammember1dev
  ```
- Reset the head to follow the remote master

  ```
  git reset --hard origin/master
  ```
- Branch off the master

  ```
  git checkout -b master_teammember1dev
  ```
- Continue with development

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Isn't [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) what you want?

Comment: You could fetch then merge master back into the branch. We tend to use relatively short lived branches (one per feature or bug) rather than having each team member use a branch. Many people collaborate on the same branches and it's rare to see the same name twice.

Comment: I'm worried by the implications of this "master_teammember1dev", this implies to me that all devs are sharing a remote, and as such this newbie who you seem not to trust their knowledge of git to, may very easily nuke anyone's work by mistake. I recommend working like Github, I highly recommend using their forking pattern; described by: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34998648/1695680 https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Comment: The last paragraph of [meagar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34998912/1290731) deserves highlighting. The accepted answer's probably more immediately helpful here, but if "your repo is _entirely_ yours" isn't the core of your git understanding you're never going to get full value out of git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on how far you're willing to stray from that model.

A good basic model is to let each developer have their own backed-up bare repository on some easily accessible server. Then, each developer would have (at least) 2 remotes: 1) The main one, from which they pull; and 2) Their *own* remote, to which they push their own history of changes once it's nice and clean.

You, being the integrator, would be able to pull from the developers' remotes, as well as to push to the main one—effectively publishing those changes to everyone.

Comment: This is really good to know thanks. I've done some testing with forking now and it seems much cleaner. The part that confused me Gitlab specifically is that they don't seem to use the terminology "pull request". You can create a merge request for branches across repositories (the root and the fork) just like you would for branches within the same repo. The following URLs told me everything I needed to get started: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/ and https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Answer (score 3):

If I were dropped into this (somewhat atypical) situation as one of your junior devs, I would do the following:

1. Run `git fetch` to update `origin/master`
2. Run `git checkout -b my_branch origin/master` to create a new branch based on the state of `origin/master`
3. Work, and commit my changes, using `git add -p` and **never** using `git commit -am`, which is the worst possible way to commit changes. It is guaranteed to eventually bite you by accidentally committing something you didn't mean to
4. Push my branch to the remote with `git push origin my_branch` and wait for you to perform the merge
5. Repeat. No other commands are necessary; starting from `#1`, I will get my changes along with the latest `origin/master` when I `fetch` and be ready to stat working again.

That said, your junior devs should be free to use whatever work flow they want. Familiarity with Git should be developed to the point where you aren't worried about these sorts of micro-optimizations to work flow. They can branch and merge locally however they want in complete isolation from you and from their peers, there is no requirement that each dev follow the same branching/merging model at all, so long as they are consistent in how they push.

Comment: Sadly my own familarity of Git is lacking as I've only used it in circumstances where I'm the only person working on that repo at a time; hence my bodged solution to keeping things together. I'll probably go with the forking approach now but thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm tempted to go in and bold the entire last paragraph.  The _only_ structure that matters is what's in repos you personally are responsible for, i.e. what they push to repos you own, not what they do in their own repos.  In fact ...